# Is it possible to make Session Identifier with IP dependent of the client machine?

Tags: java, session, jboss, jsessionid

I am using a JAVA application as client which runs on JBOSS AS 7.1.0. I would like implement a security on my application by making the session identifier dependent on the IP address of the client machine

By implementing this a session ID will be tightly coupled to the client machine IP. Other client should not use the same session ID if they are logging from other system as session ID is already consumed by other client IP

Comment: You are aware that potentially tens of thousands of PCs could connect from the same global IP, right?

Comment: Yes I am aware..but I want to try and check if this is actually possible..